# vb.net application memory consumption - where is the leak?

Tags: vb.net

I have created a little vb.net forms application that controls a 3rd party application (it's a CAD-software where my app opens CAD-projects and does some bulk output operations)

The longer the app runs the more memory it consumes and I am currently struggling to find the reason.

Meanwhile I am pretty sure that waiting for the CAD-project to be loaded causes the issue. I do check if there is a certain control within the main CAD-application with the string "Programmzweig" in it's title:

```
  lTemp = 0
    Do While lTemp = 0
      Thread.Sleep(1000)
      lTemp = GetHandle("Programmzweig", True, hwnd_Main)
    Loop
```

The function GetHandle looks like this:

```
 Public Function GetHandle(Suchbegriff As String, Children As Boolean, Optional hwnd_Parent As Integer = 0) As Integer

    If Children = False Then

      Dim hwnd As Integer
      Dim s2 As String

      Dim enumChild As New NativeMethods

      hwnd = apiGetTopWindow(apiGetDesktopWindow)

      Do

        Dim ProcId As Integer
        Dim proc As Process

        GetWindowThreadProcessId(New IntPtr(hwnd), ProcId)

        proc = Process.GetProcessById(ProcId)

        If UCase(Trim(proc.ProcessName)) = "ALL3DLL" Then

          s2 = GetWindowName(hwnd)

          If InStr(s2, Suchbegriff) > 0 Then

            GetHandle = hwnd
            enumChild.Dispose()
            Exit Function

          End If

        End If

        hwnd = apiGetWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        If hwnd = 0 Then
          'GetWindows = s1
          Exit Do
        End If
      Loop

      enumChild.Dispose()

    Else

      Dim enumerator = New WindowsEnumerator()

      For Each child As ApiWindow In enumerator.GetChildWindows(hwnd_Parent)
        If InStr(child.MainWindowTitle, Suchbegriff) > 0 Then
          GetHandle = child.hWnd
          enumerator = Nothing
          child = Nothing
          Exit For
        End If
        child = Nothing
      Next child

      enumerator = Nothing

    End If

  End Function
```

Can someone find any major issue within these code line that could cause the memory problems?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Here's NativeMethods:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class NativeMethods

  Implements IDisposable

  <DllImport("User32.dll")> _
  Private Shared Function EnumChildWindows _
     (ByVal WindowHandle As IntPtr, ByVal Callback As EnumWindowProcess, _
     ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
  End Function

  Public Delegate Function EnumWindowProcess(ByVal Handle As IntPtr, ByVal Parameter As IntPtr) As Boolean

  Public Shared Function GetChildWindows(ByVal ParentHandle As IntPtr) As IntPtr()
    Dim ChildrenList As New List(Of IntPtr)
    Dim ListHandle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(ChildrenList)
    Try
      EnumChildWindows(ParentHandle, AddressOf EnumWindow, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(ListHandle))
    Finally
      If ListHandle.IsAllocated Then ListHandle.Free()
    End Try
    Return ChildrenList.ToArray
  End Function

  Private Shared Function EnumWindow(ByVal Handle As IntPtr, ByVal Parameter As IntPtr) As Boolean
    Dim ChildrenList As List(Of IntPtr) = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(Parameter).Target
    If ChildrenList Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List(Of IntPtr)")
    ChildrenList.Add(Handle)
    Return True
  End Function

#Region "IDisposable Support"
  Private disposedValue As Boolean ' So ermitteln Sie überflüssige Aufrufe

  ' IDisposable
  Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not Me.disposedValue Then
      If disposing Then
        ' TODO: Verwalteten Zustand löschen (verwaltete Objekte).
      End If

      ' TODO: Nicht verwaltete Ressourcen (nicht verwaltete Objekte) freigeben und Finalize() unten überschreiben.
      ' TODO: Große Felder auf NULL festlegen.
    End If
    Me.disposedValue = True
  End Sub

  ' TODO: Finalize() nur überschreiben, wenn Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) oben über Code zum Freigeben von nicht verwalteten Ressourcen verfügt.
  'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
  '    ' Ändern Sie diesen Code nicht. Fügen Sie oben in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) Bereinigungscode ein.
  '    Dispose(False)
  '    MyBase.Finalize()
  'End Sub

  ' Dieser Code wird von Visual Basic hinzugefügt, um das Dispose-Muster richtig zu implementieren.
  Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    ' Ändern Sie diesen Code nicht. Fügen Sie oben in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) Bereinigungscode ein.
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
  End Sub
#End Region
```

and here comes WindowsEnumerator:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Class ApiWindow
  Public MainWindowTitle As String = ""
  Public ClassName As String = ""
  Public hWnd As Int32
End Class

''' <summary> 
''' Enumerate top-level and child windows 
''' </summary> 
''' <example> 
''' Dim enumerator As New WindowsEnumerator()
''' For Each top As ApiWindow in enumerator.GetTopLevelWindows()
'''    Console.WriteLine(top.MainWindowTitle)
'''    For Each child As ApiWindow child in enumerator.GetChildWindows(top.hWnd) 
'''        Console.WriteLine(" " + child.MainWindowTitle)
'''    Next child
''' Next top
''' </example> 
Public Class WindowsEnumerator

  Implements IDisposable

  Private Delegate Function EnumCallBackDelegate(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

  ' Top-level windows.
  Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumCallBackDelegate, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

  ' Child windows.
  Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hWndParent As Integer, ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumCallBackDelegate, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

  ' Get the window class.
  Private Declare Function GetClassName _
   Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpClassName As StringBuilder, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer

  ' Test if the window is visible--only get visible ones.
  Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer

  ' Test if the window's parent--only get the one's without parents.
  Private Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer

  ' Get window text length signature.
  Private Declare Function SendMessage _
   Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32

  ' Get window text signature.
  Private Declare Function SendMessage _
   Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As StringBuilder) As Int32

  Private _listChildren As New List(Of ApiWindow)
  Private _listTopLevel As New List(Of ApiWindow)

  Private _topLevelClass As String = ""
  Private _childClass As String = ""

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Get all top-level window information
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <returns>List of window information objects</returns>
  Public Overloads Function GetTopLevelWindows() As List(Of ApiWindow)

    EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumWindowProc, &H0)

    Return _listTopLevel

  End Function

  Public Overloads Function GetTopLevelWindows(ByVal className As String) As List(Of ApiWindow)

    _topLevelClass = className

    Return Me.GetTopLevelWindows()

  End Function

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Get all child windows for the specific windows handle (hwnd).
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <returns>List of child windows for parent window</returns>
  Public Overloads Function GetChildWindows(ByVal hwnd As Int32) As List(Of ApiWindow)

    ' Clear the window list.
    _listChildren = New List(Of ApiWindow)

    ' Start the enumeration process.
    EnumChildWindows(hwnd, AddressOf EnumChildWindowProc, &H0)

    ' Return the children list when the process is completed.
    Return _listChildren

  End Function

  Public Overloads Function GetChildWindows(ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal childClass As String) As List(Of ApiWindow)

    ' Set the search
    _childClass = childClass

    Return Me.GetChildWindows(hwnd)

  End Function

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Callback function that does the work of enumerating top-level windows.
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <param name="hwnd">Discovered Window handle</param>
  ''' <returns>1=keep going, 0=stop</returns>
  Private Function EnumWindowProc(ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32

    ' Eliminate windows that are not top-level.
    If GetParent(hwnd) = 0 AndAlso CBool(IsWindowVisible(hwnd)) Then

      ' Get the window title / class name.
      Dim window As ApiWindow = GetWindowIdentification(hwnd)

      ' Match the class name if searching for a specific window class.
      If _topLevelClass.Length = 0 OrElse window.ClassName.ToLower() = _topLevelClass.ToLower() Then
        _listTopLevel.Add(window)
      End If

    End If

    ' To continue enumeration, return True (1), and to stop enumeration 
    ' return False (0).
    ' When 1 is returned, enumeration continues until there are no 
    ' more windows left.

    Return 1

  End Function

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Callback function that does the work of enumerating child windows.
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <param name="hwnd">Discovered Window handle</param>
  ''' <returns>1=keep going, 0=stop</returns>
  Private Function EnumChildWindowProc(ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32

    Dim window As ApiWindow = GetWindowIdentification(hwnd)

    ' Attempt to match the child class, if one was specified, otherwise
    ' enumerate all the child windows.
    If _childClass.Length = 0 OrElse window.ClassName.ToLower() = _childClass.ToLower() Then
      _listChildren.Add(window)
    End If

    Return 1

  End Function

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Build the ApiWindow object to hold information about the Window object.
  ''' </summary>
  Private Function GetWindowIdentification(ByVal hwnd As Integer) As ApiWindow

    Const WM_GETTEXT As Int32 = &HD
    Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As Int32 = &HE

    Dim window As New ApiWindow()

    Dim title As New StringBuilder()

    ' Get the size of the string required to hold the window title.
    Dim size As Int32 = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)

    ' If the return is 0, there is no title.
    If size > 0 Then
      title = New StringBuilder(size + 1)

      SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, title.Capacity, title)
    End If

    ' Get the class name for the window.
    Dim classBuilder As New StringBuilder(64)
    GetClassName(hwnd, classBuilder, 64)

    ' Set the properties for the ApiWindow object.
    window.ClassName = classBuilder.ToString()
    window.MainWindowTitle = title.ToString()
    window.hWnd = hwnd

    Return window

  End Function

#Region "IDisposable Support"
  Private disposedValue As Boolean ' So ermitteln Sie überflüssige Aufrufe

  ' IDisposable
  Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not Me.disposedValue Then
      If disposing Then
        ' TODO: Verwalteten Zustand löschen (verwaltete Objekte).
      End If

      ' TODO: Nicht verwaltete Ressourcen (nicht verwaltete Objekte) freigeben und Finalize() unten überschreiben.
      ' TODO: Große Felder auf NULL festlegen.
    End If
    Me.disposedValue = True
  End Sub

  ' TODO: Finalize() nur überschreiben, wenn Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) oben über Code zum Freigeben von nicht verwalteten Ressourcen verfügt.
  'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
  '    ' Ändern Sie diesen Code nicht. Fügen Sie oben in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) Bereinigungscode ein.
  '    Dispose(False)
  '    MyBase.Finalize()
  'End Sub

  ' Dieser Code wird von Visual Basic hinzugefügt, um das Dispose-Muster richtig zu implementieren.
  Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    ' Ändern Sie diesen Code nicht. Fügen Sie oben in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) Bereinigungscode ein.
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
  End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Comment: You would need to show `NativeMethods` and `WindowsEnumerator`.

Comment: I have updated the original post now with these codes!

Comment: There are *numeroues* issues with this code on every level. Both `NativeMethods` and `WindowsEnumerator` should be modules, not classes, and not implement `IDisposable`. You are not using `NativeMethods`. Everything inside `WindowsEnumerator` is very wrong about the data types. Inside `GetHandle` you (apparently) have yet another set of native methods duplicating those from `WindowsEnumerator` that you are using to manually loop over top level windows (instead of using the methods from `WindowsEnumerator`), which you have not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason for `NativeMethods` and `WindowsEnumerator` to implement `IDisposable`, by doing so they only upset the garbage collector's finalizers routines. In fact, they are in principle static classes (modules).
Then, the API declarations in `WindowsEnumerator` are all wrong.
Then, you are not using `NativeMethods`. Inside `GetHandle` you (apparently) have yet another set of native methods duplicating those from `WindowsEnumerator` that you are using to manually loop over top level windows (instead of using the methods from `WindowsEnumerator`), which you have not shown.

It would appear that this code should have been written as:

**WindowsEnumerator.vb**

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Module WindowsEnumerator
    Public Class ApiWindow
        Public MainWindowTitle As String = String.Empty
        Public ClassName As String = String.Empty
        Public hWnd As IntPtr
    End Class

    Private Delegate Function EnumWindowProcess(ByVal Handle As IntPtr, ByVal Parameter As IntPtr) As Boolean

    ' Top-level windows.
    <DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Function EnumWindows _
        (ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumWindowProcess, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=False)>
    Private Function EnumChildWindows _
       (ByVal WindowHandle As IntPtr, ByVal Callback As EnumWindowProcess, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function


    ' Get the window class.
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=False)>
    Private Function GetClassName _
        (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpClassName As StringBuilder, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    ' Test if the window is visible--only get visible ones.
    <DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=False)>
    Private Function IsWindowVisible _
        (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function


    ' Test if the window's parent--only get the one's without parents.
    <DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=False)>
    Private Function GetParent _
        (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    ' Get window text length signature.
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Function SendMessage _
        (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    ' Get window text signature.
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Function SendMessage _
        (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As StringBuilder) As IntPtr
    End Function


    <DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Function GetWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal uCmd As GetWindowCommands) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Public Enum GetWindowCommands As Integer
        GW_HWNDFIRST = 0
        GW_HWNDLAST = 1
        GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
        GW_HWNDPREV = 3
        GW_OWNER = 4
        GW_CHILD = 5
        GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
    End Enum

    <DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=False)>
    Private Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, <Out> ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Function GetTopWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=False)>
    Public Function GetDesktopWindow() As IntPtr
    End Function


    Public Function GetWindowProcessId(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Integer
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, GetWindowProcessId)
    End Function


    Public Function GetTopLevelWindows() As List(Of ApiWindow)
        Return GetTopLevelWindows(Nothing)
    End Function

    Public Function GetTopLevelWindows(ByVal className As String) As List(Of ApiWindow)

        Dim listTopLevel As New List(Of ApiWindow)

        EnumWindows(Function(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal Parameter As IntPtr)
                        ' Eliminate windows that are not top-level.
                        If GetParent(hwnd) = IntPtr.Zero AndAlso IsWindowVisible(hwnd) Then

                            ' Get the window title / class name.
                            Dim window As ApiWindow = GetWindowIdentification(hwnd)

                            ' Match the class name if searching for a specific window class.
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(className) OrElse String.Equals(window.ClassName, className, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                                listTopLevel.Add(window)
                            End If

                        End If

                        ' To continue enumeration, return True, and to stop enumeration 
                        ' return False.
                        ' When True is returned, enumeration continues until there are no 
                        ' more windows left.

                        Return True
                    End Function,
                    IntPtr.Zero)

        Return listTopLevel

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get all child windows for the specific windows handle (hwnd).
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>List of child windows for parent window</returns>
    Public Function GetChildWindows(ByVal ParentHwnd As IntPtr) As List(Of ApiWindow)
        Return GetChildWindows(ParentHwnd, Nothing)
    End Function

    Public Function GetChildWindows(ByVal ParentHwnd As IntPtr, ByVal ChildClass As String) As List(Of ApiWindow)

        ' Clear the window list.
        Dim listChildren = New List(Of ApiWindow)

        ' Start the enumeration process.
        EnumChildWindows(ParentHwnd, Function(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal Parameter As IntPtr)
                                         Dim window As ApiWindow = GetWindowIdentification(hwnd)

                                         ' Attempt to match the child class, if one was specified, otherwise
                                         ' enumerate all the child windows.
                                         If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ChildClass) OrElse String.Equals(window.ClassName, ChildClass, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                                             listChildren.Add(window)
                                         End If

                                         Return True
                                     End Function,
                                     IntPtr.Zero)

        ' Return the children list when the process is completed.
        Return listChildren

    End Function


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Build the ApiWindow object to hold information about the Window object.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Function GetWindowIdentification(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As ApiWindow

        Const WM_GETTEXT As Integer = &HD&
        Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As Integer = &HE&

        Dim window As New ApiWindow()

        Dim title As StringBuilder = Nothing
        Dim class_name_length As Integer = 0
        Dim title_length As Integer = 0

        ' Get the size of the string required to hold the window title.
        Dim size As IntPtr = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)

        ' If the return is 0, there is no title.
        If size.ToInt32() > 0 Then
            title = New StringBuilder(size.ToInt32() + 1)

            title_length = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, New IntPtr(title.Capacity), title).ToInt32()
        End If

        ' Get the class name for the window.
        Dim classBuilder As New StringBuilder(64)
        class_name_length = GetClassName(hwnd, classBuilder, 64)

        ' Set the properties for the ApiWindow object.
        window.ClassName = classBuilder.ToString(0, class_name_length)
        window.MainWindowTitle = If(title?.ToString(0, title_length), String.Empty)
        window.hWnd = hwnd

        Return window

    End Function

End Module
```

```vb
Public Function GetHandle(ByVal Suchbegriff As String, ByVal Children As Boolean) As IntPtr
    Return GetHandle(Suchbegriff, Children, IntPtr.Zero)
End Function

Public Function GetHandle(ByVal Suchbegriff As String, ByVal Children As Boolean, ByVal hwnd_Parent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    If Children Then

        For Each child As ApiWindow In WindowsEnumerator.GetChildWindows(hwnd_Parent)
            If InStr(child.MainWindowTitle, Suchbegriff) > 0 Then
                Return child.hWnd
            End If
        Next

    Else

        Dim hwnd = WindowsEnumerator.GetTopWindow(WindowsEnumerator.GetDesktopWindow())

        Do Until hwnd = IntPtr.Zero
            Using proc = Process.GetProcessById(WindowsEnumerator.GetWindowProcessId(hwnd))
                If String.Equals(Trim(proc.ProcessName), "ALL3DLL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                    If InStr(WindowsEnumerator.GetWindowIdentification(hwnd).MainWindowTitle, Suchbegriff) > 0 Then
                        Return hwnd
                    End If
                End If
            End Using

            hwnd = WindowsEnumerator.GetWindow(hwnd, GetWindowCommands.GW_HWNDNEXT)
        Loop

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: A big THANK YOU @GSerg ...

I just tried your code and it seems to run without the memory leaks now. Thank you very much for helping a complete noob to get his job done!